# Vue how to test response to event emitted by child in parent

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I'm trying to setup unit testing on a new Vue project that I'm working on. This is my first time doing unit testing on the frontend.  I'm using Jest and Vue-test-utils.

I've gotten stuck on how to test one of my components. The basic set up is like this:

```
<Grid>
    <GridItem @clicked="toggleItem"/>
</Grid>
```

The toggleItem method on the parent emits an 'input' event. I'm trying to test that when the  emits a 'clicked' event, the parent emits an 'input' event.

I have setup my test to shallowMount the parent component. This is what my test looks like:

```
it('clicking a GridItem should emit and input event', async () => {
  const gridItems = wrapper.findAll(GridItem);
  await gridItems.at(0).vm.$emit('clicked');
  expect(wrapper.emitted().input.length).toBe('1');
});
```

However, when I run this test, I get this error

```
TypeError: _vm.toggleItem is not a function
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?